# CSS: small problem with float

Tags: css, css-float

Hihi,

I have a small problem, I´ve done it before but as CSS behave sometimes it´s OK on time
but next time it shows a bug.

As you can see the red area (main content) doesn´t flow as it should

I must be missing something but why not post the problem while I go to the grocery store :)

As I say, guess it´s something tiny...

[enter link description here](http://trekkingtravel.is/admin/control.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sidebar { 
        display:block; 
        float:left; 
        width:170px; 
        height:auto; 
        min-height:400px;
        background:#f9f9f9;
        border: solid 1px #eaeaea;
        border-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
}

#main { display:block; float:right; width:766px; height:auto; min-height:400px; background:red; }
```

Use this css. it will work.

Answer (score 2):

The sitebar div has a width of 20%, but also has a border of 1px on both sides. Those 2 pixels are added to the inner width of 20%, so that leaves no 80% for the main div.

So set the width of main on 79%, or add:

```
margin: 0 -1px 0 -1px;
```

But since you give the container a fixed width, why then do you style in percentage?

Comment: Yes, I see that styling in percentages was not a good idea in this case... that was the reason it haven´t happen before because i´ve always used pixels

Just saw some tutorial recommending using % sometimes for layout floating

Comment: For liquid layouts you can or should indeed, but when the width of the parent container is fixed we're not talking about a liquid layout.

Comment: ok, so it´s more when designing a full-screen interface adapting to the users screen resolution?

Comment: Yes, for adapting to the screen resolution or to the browser window dimensions, but the design isn't necessarily full-screen.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting the width on your red container to `width: 79%`. Somehow, it overflows when you set it so both make 100%.

Perhaps it would be better to work pixel perfect here and put pixel values instead of using percent, since your container is of a fixed width anyway.

Hope that helps you.